# Javascript confirm dialog - prevent event handler firing?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've got a form with a number of fields and a few checkboxes. When the user clicks save, if a certain checkbox isn't checked, they're prompted with a 'Confirm' dialog box asking if they still want to save the form. If they click okay, the button should fire it's event handler normally, but if they click cancel, nothing should happen.

```
function checkVerification(checkBox)
{
    if (!document.getElementById(checkBox).checked)
    {
        confirm('Worksheet has not been verified. Save anyway?');            
    }
}
```

As of right now, the Save button's event handler fires regardless of the user's choice. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tie the return value of the confirm dialog to the `OnClientClick` of the button, like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" ... />
```

In this case, if user clicks *Yes* the page will perform a postback. If the user clicks *No* the postback will be aborted.

After looking at your comment, try this:

```
btnSave.OnClientClick = String.Format("return checkVerify('{0}');", cbVerified.ClientID);
```

And in your JavaScript function:

```
function checkVerify(checkBox)
{ 
    bool continue = true;
    if(!document.getElementById(checkBox).checked) {
        continue = confirm('Worksheet not verified. Would you like to save?');
    } 
    return continue;
}
```

Comment: Hey James, thanks for your reply. I'm currently passing the ClientID of the checkbox to the Javascript function... <br>btnSave.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "return checkVerify('" + cbVerified.ClientID + "')");<br>The Javascript function is written as follows: <br>function checkVerify(checkBox)
 {
     if(!document.getElementById(checkBox).checked === true) 
     {
         if(confirm('Worksheet not verified. Would you like to save?'))
         {
             return true;
         }
         else
         {
             return false;
         }
     }
 }<br> Save is clicked..

Comment: And the page posts back without calling the btnSave's event handler. Apologies for the formatting of the previous comment. EDIT: Also, no dialog is displayed.

Comment: `OnClientClick` is a property of Button, so you don't need to add it as an attribute. Just use `btnSave.OnClientClick = ...`

Answer (score 2):

Just return false if the user declines to save, like this:

```
return confirm('Worksheet has not been verified. Save anyway?');
```

`confirm()` will return `true` if the user clicked 'Yes' and `false` if they clicked 'No.'  Returning `false` instructs the browser to stop processing the event normally.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ok = confirm('Worksheet has not been verified. Save anyway?');
if (ok) {
    // trigger
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the verification is bound to the onsubmit event you can just return false from the handler and the form won't be submitted.

Also, if you are using jQuery, the method event.preventDefault() would do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code it's hard to tell exactly, BUT one problem could be your if statement. To ensure proper type checking use === instead of assuming your value is a boolean.

if(document.getElementById(checkBox).checked === false) { ... }

You could also have more than one checkbox on the page with the same id value...if one is checked and one isn't document.getElementById might be getting the one that isn't checked.

Hope that helps.